# Make a symlink in bash with two relative paths

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, ln

I have two directories in my home: `~/dir1` and `~/dir2` with a file in the first: `~/dir1/file.txt` Is there any way that I can make a symlink to it from `~/dir2` without moving to `~/` and if not why is that the case?

I've tried from `~/` running:

```
$ ln -s ./dir1/file.txt ./dir2/file.txt
```

but as I'd expect, that causes the resultant symlink to effectively point at `~/dir1/dir2/file.txt` which makes sense but isn't what I actually want.

I've also tried:

```
$ ln -s ./dir1/file.txt ../dir2/file.txt
```

Which returns:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link `../dir2/file.txt': No such file or directory
```

I'd expect this to just create a symlink `~/dir2/file.txt` pointing to `~/../dir1/file.txt`

So I suppose my real question is this: can I force `ln` to make a symlink to a file that it doesn't think exists?

**Edit:**
For extra clarity as to what I'm trying to achieve, I want a single command that I can run from my home directory that will effectively do:

```
pushd dir2/ && ln -s ../dir1/file.txt && popd
```

or in Python (this is the closest I've come to what I want):

```
echo "import os; os.symlink('../dir1/file.txt', './dir2/file.txt')" | python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of

1. Use absolute paths

   ```
   $ ln -s ~/dir1/file.txt ~/dir2
   $ readlink dir2/file.txt 
   /home/terdon/dir1/file.txt
   ```
2. Use the right relative paths

   ```
   $ ln -s ../dir1/file.txt dir2/
   $ readlink dir2/file.txt 
   ../dir1/file.txt
   ```

Depending on your use case, one may be better than the other. Just remember that when creating links using relative paths, the paths *must be relative to the target* and not to your current location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first suggestion will work if I had absolute paths but I specifically interested in relative paths. Your second suggestion is synonymous with my second attempted command (missing the destination filename) but I got a file not found error (see above) on the *first* argument. Can I ask which linux distribution you are using?

Comment: @nettux443 huh, that's strange. I'm on LMDE (basically Debian testing) and bash `4.2.45`. Note that my second suggestion is _not_ the same as yours. You used `./dir` and I'm using `../dir`. The idea is that the path needs to be relative to the target. If you want to include the link's name, use `ln -s ../dir1/file.txt ~/dir2/foo` that will still work. It will also work irrespective of where you are. I just tried the above from `/etc` and it correctly created a file at `~/dir2/foo` pointing to `~/dir1/file.txt`.

Comment: @nettux443 no, `ln` only checks whether the file it creates exists. It's your job to make sure that the target is real. This will give no error for example: `ln -s /fruble/bargle/bob /tmp/foo`, it will happily and silently create a broken link.

Comment: Sorry you are right my second answer is not the same as your suggestion. Therein lies the problem. Your suggestion is what I *meant* to try....  hopefully won't make that mistake again!

Comment: @nettux443 lol, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kinda confusing.

1. You asked *"Is there any way that I can make a symlink to it from `~/dir1` [...] ?"*  I suppose you meant "from `~/dir2`", based on the rest of your post?
2. Your first command

   `$ ln -s ./dir1/file.txt ./dir2/file.txt`

   does not do what you think it does.  Assuming you're still in your home directory, the above command creates a symlink whose own path is `~/dir2/file.txt`, and this symlink points *literally* to the path `./dir1/file.txt`.  Because said symlink resides in the directory `~/dir2`, such target path resolves to `~/dir2/./dir1/file.txt`, which further resolves to `~/dir2/dir1/file.txt` (probably non-existent and not what you want).  So I doubt why you said it resolves to `~/dir1/dir2/file.txt`.
3. Your 2nd command fails because there's no directory `../dir2` to put the symlink in, and that's what the error message meant.
4. To answer your question, yes.  The OS doesn't care whether your symlink points to a path with no valid filesystem object present.

Probably what you really want is something like

```
ln -s ../dir1/file.txt ./dir2/file.txt
```

I guess?  This command creates a symlink whose own path is `./dir2/file.txt`, and its target is the literal relative path `../dir1/file.txt`.  The final, absolute path pointed to by the symlink is `~/dir2/../dir1/file.txt`, which resolves to `~/dir1/file.txt`.

Note that the `~` symbol is a shell expandable character which expands to the absolute path of your home directory.  `~`-expansion is not part of OS path resolution.

#### Suggested reading

Linux manpages of `path_resolution(7)`, `symlink(7)`, `ln(1)` and `ln(1p)`.

#### Edit

Clarifications & suggested reading.

Comment: I understand why my first command doesn't work, that I didn't expect to work but I thought I'd try it. The second command I feel would work if I could force it to make the link. Note your suggested command's arguments are the wrong way round. ````ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/new/link```` the command you've written is trying to make a link ````~/dir1/file.txt```` pointing to ````~/dir2/file.txt```` (backwards!!) :)

Comment: see my edited question for more detailed info on what I'm trying to achieve.