# symbolic links that will not break even after copying

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I want to create a symbolic link which will not break even after copying the entire directory( which includes the link and its target) in a pendrive/sd-card and using the pendrive/sd-card in other system.

For ex:

```
 S70pppd-dns -> ../init.d/pppd-dns  
 S77hello_init -> /home/silviya/package/rootfs/etc/init.d/hello_init
```

Here, the link for hello_init is created by me, other one is there by default.
How can I create the symbolic link as shown below ??
**S70hello_init -> ../init.d/hello_init**

NOTE:
I created the link using the command:

```
ln -s 'target_file' 'symbolic_link'
```

Comment: I don't think that would be possible because the path would change from computer to computer

Comment: Its possible by symlink command.. But I don't know how to use it

Comment: look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/389997/how-to-override-update-a-symlink and http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/09/using-ln-sf-to-replace-symlink-to.html

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your real problem. Is anything wrong with ln  -s  ../init.d/hello_init S70hello_init? It creates the slink right away.

Comment: Good news !! I have done it ... Refer to this link : https://superuser.com/questions/753001/make-a-symlink-in-bash-with-two-relative-paths